# How to change the background colour of a Keynote presentation gradually each slide?

Tags: keynote

Can I automatically change the background colour of a Keynote presentation? I would like to have a lighter shade of a colour on the first slide and gradually darken each slide such that I end up with black on the last slide.

Even more awesome would be if I could go through a pre-specified gradient (e.g. a rainbow) instead of a "simple" light-dark transition.

I have 40 slides, and doing this manually is quite tedious.

*Don't worry, it's not for an actual presentation.*

Comment: Interesting.  If the change on adjacent slides is not noticeable...

Comment: @GEdgar I'm not sure what you mean. Could you please explain your comment?